# Unable to generate java files from wadl

Tags: rest, maven, wadl

**Error:**

`'[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'wadl' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories'`

**When:** am trying to generate java files by referring the below link from the section 'Maven Plug-in Usage'

https://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem for me was due to the fact that in order for Maven to resolve the `wadl` prefix you need to add the plugin groups to you `settings.xml`.

```
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.jvnet.ws.wadl</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
```

That means that when you run the `wadl:generate` command it will also look in the `org.jvnet.ws.wadl` group for a match.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that your pom.xml has the below repository, plugin repository and dependency?

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>wadl-repository</id>
      <name>WADL Maven Repository</name>
      <url>https://wadl.dev.java.net/nonav/repository/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wadl-snapshots</id>
      <name>WADL Snapshots Repository</name>
      <url>https://wadl.dev.java.net/nonav/snapshots</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wadl-snapshots</id>
      <name>WADL Snapshots Repository</name>
      <url>https://wadl.dev.java.net/nonav/snapshots</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.ws.wadl</groupId>
      <artifactId>wadl-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Yes, it has but still throwing error '[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'wadl' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories'

Comment: Its very hard to find the issue without pom.xml. Can you update the question with your pom.xml